# How to bind dynamic NSNumber Object to SQLite query?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm wondering how to bind an NSNumber object into a sqlite3 query:

```
const char *sql = "select name from myTable where section_id=1 order by name ASC";
```

I have a NSNumber object called 'nmbr' and want to assign its value to the section id..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const char *sql = "select name from myTable where section_id=? order by name ASC";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_handle, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK;
NSNumber sid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
sqlite3_bind_int  (stmt, 1, [sid intValue]);   
sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_reset(stmt);
```

Remember: you should deal with error return codes. For the sake of simplicity I am ignoring them here.